# Different meanings of "have you seen my"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Am I right in thinking that "have you seen my new phone?" can be used to ask two things:

1. I can't find my phone, have you seen it, do you know where it is?
2. I have bought a new phone and I want to show it to you.

Comment: Yes, your cited text can have either of those meanings. Context will normally make it blindingly obvious which meaning is intended - but even without additional context, I'd et money that the presence or absence of the specific word ***new*** would disambiguate in the vast majority of usages. (If it's just "lost", you wouldn't normally include "new" - that's for when you want to show off your new toys! :)

Comment: 'Have you seen the mess that the dog has made on the carpet?' has another implication.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: In ***my*** household, the standard "rules of engagement" for dealing with a pet "indiscretion" require that the first person to discover it is the one who should deal with it. So I might go for *Have you seen **any** mess that the dog **might have** made on the carpet?* on the grounds of "plausible deniability" (I haven't actually seen it myself, so I can't know for sure if there's anything that needs to be dealt with! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly.  The difference would be apparent from both context and from emphasis; for the latter:

"Have ***you*** seen my (new) phone?" *(I already found my ***old*** phone.)*  The "new" would be underemphasized, as it is just clarifying which phone is sought.

Although I would probably instead say "Have you seen my new phone *anywhere*?" or even "Do you know where my new phone might be?".

"Have you seen my ***new phone***?"  (I want you to see it, in part because it is new.)

Other emphases give us other meanings too. "Have ***you*** seen my new phone?" (I already showed it to Alice and Bob.)